# Select one of two nested sheets based on one of the values

Tags: python, list

I have two lists with some nested lists. Every nested list has an integer as a first item and a string as a second. Needed an another list, which contains nested lists, with rows that occurred in both given lists and a large number as the first item.

```
given

a = [[1,'one'], [2,'two'], [3,'three'],[10,'ten']]
b = [[3,'one'], [1,'two'],[5,'three']]

needed:

c = [[3,'one'],[2,'two'],[5,'three']]
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. Please include your attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: Hi! Thank you! Is it one of the rule to include your own attempt? In this case I didn't have a good one :(

Comment: It's good practice to show that you are trying to solve the problem yourself. It shows that what you have attempted, gives others an idea of your understanding and sometimes a place to start of the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with your given data you could use a list comprehension with the built-in function `zip`:

```
a = [[1,'one'], [2,'two'], [3,'three'],[10,'ten']]
b = [[3,'one'], [1,'two'],[5,'three']]


[[max(e[0], i[0]), e[1]] for e, i in zip(a, b)]
```

output:

```
[[3,'one'],[2,'two'],[5,'three']]
```

---

if in your lists `a`, and `b` you do not have the sublists in the same order (base one the string) you  could use:

```
da = dict((e[::-1] for e in a))
db = dict((e[::-1] for e in b))

[[max(da[k], db[k]), k] for k in set(da).intersection(db)]
```